# Compare two items in one NSArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, comparison, nsarray

I have an array containing twenty items. I want to search through the array, comparing one item to the next one in the array, and then print the larger item. I have already sorted the array. I just want to compare the two items, check what the remainder is between the two values, and if it's greater than say, four, print the larger item.

Comment: Between every pair of values, or the values at two specific indexes, or what? Are your values `NSNumber`s?

Comment: Iterate.  There are several different ways to do it, but a plain old `for` loop should do fine.

Comment: Some good practices for comparison [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it?rq=1)

Comment: It is an array of Objects, which has a name which is NSString and points which is an int. I want to compare the integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray* arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:7],
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
    nil
];

int len = [arr count];

for (int i=0; i < len-1; ++i) {

    int num1 = [[arr objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    int num2 = [[arr objectAtIndex:i+1] intValue];

    if ( num2-num1 > 4 ) {
        NSLog(@"%d", num2);
    }
}

 --output:--
    6
```

Comment: num2 will be num1 in the next iteration. Simply set num1 one time before entering the for loop, which should run from 1 - <len and pass num2 to num1 at the end of the loop. Reduces accesses to the array by 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSEnumerator *itemEnumerator = [theArray objectEnumerator];
YourClass *lastObject = [itemEnumerator nextObject];
YourClass *compareObject;
while( (compareObject = [itemEnumerator nextObject]) != nil)
{
  if( /* place your condition here */ )
  {
     NSLog( … );
  }
  lastObject = compareObject;
}
```

Typped in Safari